# How to append items in a Serverless YAML list?

Tags: list, lambda, yaml, append, serverless

I'm defining the `patterns` property in `serverless.yml` but I'm having a hard time appending some values to a common already defined array of values.

```
custom:
  commonPatterns:
    - "!node_modules/**"
    - "!docs/**"
    - "!.idea/**"
    - "!bin/darwin/**"
    - "!coverage/**"
    - "!src/**"
    - "src/errors/**"
    - "src/helpers/**"
```

I need to include and exclude many paths from 4 lambdas and I want to avoid copy-paste them everywhere, so I created a `commonPattern` list under `custom` and requested it with `${self:custom.commonPatterns}` inside the `patterns` prop.

Now I need to specify to include an additional file per each lambda, along with those from the `commonPatterns` but I cannot append the value as follows:

```
functions:
  get:
    package:
      individually: true
      patterns: 
        ${self:custom.commonPatterns}
        - "src/get.js"
  post:
    package:
      individually: true
      patterns: 
        ${self:custom.commonPatterns}
        - "src/post.js"
  delete:
    package:
      individually: true
      patterns: 
        ${self:custom.commonPatterns}
        - "src/delete.js"
```

It returns `bad indentation of a mapping entry` when testing the config with `sls print`.

Is there a way to make this into a single array after config such as this?

```
patterns:
  - "!node_modules/**"
  - "!docs/**"
  - "!.idea/**"
  - "!bin/darwin/**"
  - "!coverage/**"
  - "!src/**"
  - "src/errors/**"
  - "src/helpers/**"
  - "src/get.js" # or "src/post.js" or "src/delete.js"
```

Answer (score 0):

Update, in case someone will ever land here.
There is **NO way** to do what I'm trying to but I've been able to reduce the patterns to just 4 by using the exclude rule (**!**) of Serverless V3

```
functions:
  get:
    package:
      individually: true
      patterns: 
        - "!**"                  # This will exclude everything
        - "src/errors/**"        # then include what you need
        - "src/helpers/**"       # ...
        - "src/get.js"           # ...
  post:
    package:
      individually: true
      patterns: 
        - "!**"                  # This will exclude everything
        - "src/errors/**"        # then include what you need
        - "src/helpers/**"       # ...
        - "src/get.js"           # ...
  delete:
    package:
      individually: true
      patterns: 
        - "!**"                  # This will exclude everything
        - "src/errors/**"        # then include what you need
        - "src/helpers/**"       # ...
        - "src/get.js"           # ...
```

Even though it's not a solution for the topic raised, this helps keep relatively clean the `serverless.yml`